# error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function

Tags: c

I'm developing a small library for a PID controller using avr-gcc.In spite of declaring the function in the header file and defining it separately in a .c file the compiler is throwing the following errors:

```
Compiling C: pid.c
avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega16 -I. -gdwarf-2 -DF_CPU=1000000UL -Os -funsigned-char -                 
funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wa,-  
adhlns=./pid.lst  -std=gnu99 -MMD -MP -MF .dep/pid.o.d pid.c -o pid.o 
pid.c:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
pid.c:5: warning: function declaration isn't a prototype
pid.c:5: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function
pid.c:5: error: conflicting types for 'PID_init'
pid.h:23: error: previous declaration of 'PID_init' was here
pid.c: In function 'PID_init':
pid.c:5: error: parameter name omitted
```

The header file contents of pid.h are as follows:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>

#ifndef PID_CONTROLLER
#define PID_CONTROLLER
struct PIDCONTROL

{

float error;
float prev_error;
float Kp;
float Ki;
float Kd;                       
float pid;
float P;
float I;
float D;
float setpoint;

};

void PID_init(float,float,float,float,struct PIDCONTROL*);

float PID(float,struct PIDCONTROL*);                        

#endif
```

The definitions for the declared functions have been made in pid.c which contains the code shown below:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include "pid.h"

void PID_init(float SP,float Kp,float Ki,float Kd,struct PIDCONTROL *a)

{

a->Kp=Kp;

a->Ki=Ki;

a->Kd=Kd;

a->pid=0;

a->setpoint=SP;

a->prev_error=0;

}


float PID(float PV,struct PIDCONTROL *a)

{

a->error=(a->setpoint)-PV;

a->P=(a->Kp)*(a->error);

(a->I)+=(a->Ki)*(a->error)*1.024;

a->D=(a->Kd)*((a->error)-(a->prev_error))/1.024;

a->pid=(a->P)+(a->I)+(a->D);

a->prev_error=a->error;

return(a->pid);

}
```

I couldn't just figure out what's wrong with the code. Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding a typedef for the struct, and using that as a parameter in the function definitions?

Comment: You might want to run gcc -E to expand all the macros, put the result in a .c file, and then compile that, in case one of your identifiers is being defined in one of your headers. Also best practice calls for putting your #includes inside the include guard in your header; otherwise gcc can't optimize to read the header only once if it gets included more than once. And your include guard should be called something like PID_CONTROLLER_H so it isn't likely to coincide with a type or variable name.

Comment: @roelofs: There's no reason to think that would help.

Comment: @KeithThompson - fair enough - I just like it for readability.  Just a comment ;)

Comment: After I delete the `#include` directives for `<avr/io.h>` and `<util/delay.h>`, it compiles without error for me. Most likely there's something wrong in one of those headers. (Incidentally, the entire contents of `pid.h`, including the `#include` directives, should probably be inside the include guards; that's not the problem, though.)

Comment: @roelofs: Opinions vary on that point; mine is that referring to the type as `struct PIDCONTROL` improves readability. The type already has a perfectly good name; why use a `typedef` to give it another one?

Comment: I've edited your code to make it a bit easier to read, adding indentation and deleting extraneous blank lines. **CORRECTION**: I've rolled back my edit because I realized it changes the line numbers referred to in the error messages. Is that the *exact* code you compiled, copy-and-pasted from your source file into the question?

Comment: It's the exact code I have it in my notepad. I tried compiling the code with the header file declaration within the include guards too. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: @KeithThompson one good reason is that if you make a typo (e.g. `struct PIDCOTNROL`) it is treated as an implicit declaration of a new struct type; however if you make a typo in the typedef version you immediately get an error for undeclared identifier

Comment: Just test that all de identifiers you use for the function parameters are not declared as macros in some of the includes.  I suspect of the `SP` identifier, for example.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily comment out the `#include` directives for `<avr/io.h>` and `<util/delay.h>`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: That's a good point, and one that I haven't thought of before. You haven't changed my mind, but you've given me something to think about.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, I expect that commenting out those `#include` directives will eliminate the error message. If so, uncomment one, then the other, to see which one is causing the problem. Then examine both headers (and whatever they include) for macro definitions or anything else that might interfere with your source. Another thing to try: temporarily change the name of your `PID_init` function.

Comment: @Luis Colorado spot on dude! Thanks a ton. I just renamed SP as setp and the code was successfully compiled without any errors.
Thanks fellas for your contribution too. Learnt new things

Comment: SP is commonly the name given to the stack pointer, so that's what made me in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The `avr/io.h` file also brings in `avr/common.h` which contains this little snippet:

```
/*
    Stack pointer register.
        AVR architecture 1 has no RAM, thus no stack pointer.
        All other architectures do have a stack pointer. Some devices have only
            less than 256 bytes of possible RAM locations (128 Bytes of SRAM
            and no option for external RAM), thus SPH is officially "reserved"
            for them.
*/

# ifndef SP
    # define SP _SFR_MEM16(0x3D)
# endif
```

(it's actually a bit more complicated than that, with multiple paths depending on your architecture, but that cut down example shows what the actual problem *is,* at least).

It's actually defining a pre-processor macro for `SP` which means, when you attempt to use that in your code with a function definition along the lines of:

```
void PID_init(float SP,float Kp,float Ki,float Kd,struct PIDCONTROL *a)
```

what you'll *actually* get is something like:

```
void PID_init(float _SFR_MEM16(0x3D),float Kp,float Ki,float Kd,struct PIDCONTROL *a)
```

which will cause the compiler phase to complain bitterly.

I'm actually a big believer in reasonably self-describing variable names so would generally choose something more verbose than `SP` but you'll probably find that, even if you make it `mySP`, it'll fix the immediate problem.